# Constraint implication as a constraint

Tags: haskell, ghc, rank-n-types

How can I encode a constraint implication in Haskell into a new constraint? In my example, I want to require that every `Functor c d f` needs to be such that `Obj c x` implies `Obj c (f x)`.  I am writing the constraint `forall x . Obj c x => Obj d (f x)`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints     #-}

import Prelude hiding (id, Functor, fmap)
import Data.Kind

class Category c where                            
  type Obj c a :: Constraint                    
  id :: (Obj c x) => c x x                        
  comp :: (Obj c x) => c y z -> c x y -> c x z    

class ( Category c, Category d, forall x . Obj c x => Obj d (f x))
      => Functor c d f where
  fmap :: (Obj c x, Obj c y) => c x y -> d (f x) (f y)

doublefmap :: forall c f x . (Category c , Functor c c f, Obj c x)
           => c x x -> c (f (f x)) (f (f x))
doublefmap = fmap @c @c @f . fmap @c @c @f
```

But this produces the following error:

```
Minimal.hs:27:14: error:
    • Could not deduce: Obj c (f x) arising from a use of ‘fmap’
      from the context: (Functor c c f, Obj c x)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   doublefmap :: forall (c :: * -> * -> *) (f :: * -> *) x.
                                 (Category c, Functor c c f, Obj c x) =>
                                 c x x -> c (f (f x)) (f (f x))
        at Minimal.hs:(25,1)-(26,44)
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘fmap @c @c @f’
      In the expression: fmap @c @c @f . fmap @c @c @f
      In an equation for ‘doublefmap’:
          doublefmap = fmap @c @c @f . fmap @c @c @f
    • Relevant bindings include
        doublefmap :: c x x -> c (f (f x)) (f (f x))
          (bound at Minimal.hs:27:1)
```

What am I doing wrong here? What additional hints should I give the compiler? Is there any better way of achieving this?

My guess is that I would need to use `Data.Constraint` and `:-`, but how?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me: the return type of `fmap @c @c @f` would be `c (f x) (f x)`. If you want to use that as input type for `fmap @c @c @f`, you need `Obj c (f x)`, which is exactly what the error message is saying.

Comment: Right now, I am adding `fobj :: forall x. Obj c x :- Obj c (f x)` to the definition of `Functor` and then using the `(\\)` operator from `Data.Constraint` to get what I want. It is a bit verbose, however. Is there any better solution?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Ok, but why is it not able to deduce that from `Obj c x => Obj d (f x)`? How can I make it deduce that constraint automatically?

Comment: I think this is related. The last comment shows what I am trying to achieve, but it seems that there is no solution, at least yet. https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/5927

Comment: Why would it be automatically deduced? What makes you sure this is a valid implication for any `f`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Providing the instance for `Functor c c f` requires `Obj c x => Obj d (f x)` to hold.

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work, but I do not know if this is an easier way. It uses the operator `(\\)` from `Data.Constraint`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints     #-}

import Prelude hiding (id, Functor, fmap)
import Data.Constraint

class Category c where                            
  type Obj c a :: Constraint
  id :: (Obj c x) => c x x
  comp :: (Obj c x) => c y z -> c x y -> c x z    

class (Category c, Category d) => Functor c d f where
  fobj :: forall x. Obj c x :- Obj c (f x)
  fmap :: (Obj c x, Obj c y) => c x y -> d (f x) (f y)

doublefmap :: forall c f x . (Category c , Functor c c f, Obj c x)
           => c x x -> c (f (f x)) (f (f x))
doublefmap = (fmap @c @c @f . fmap @c @c @f) \\ fobj @c @c @f @x
```

Comment: With this solution, everytime one declares an instance of Category, one needs to construct a `fobj` using `Data.Constraint`. It would be nice to find a way for this to be automatically deduced by GHC.

Comment: perhaps you could use a default definition (perhaps with a default signature) to provide that implementation automatically. Something like `default fobj :: (forall x. Obj c x => Obj c (f x)) => Obj c x :- Obj c (f x); fobj = Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a second solution without using `Data.Constraint` that (at least to me) seems a bit more elegant.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds           #-}

import Prelude hiding (id, Functor, fmap)

class Category objc c where                            
  id :: (objc x) => c x x
  comp :: (objc x) => c y z -> c x y -> c x z

class (Category objc c, Category objd d, forall x . (objc x) => objd (f x))
      => Functor objc c objd d f where
  fmap :: (objc x, objc y) => c x y -> d (f x) (f y)

doublefmap :: forall c f x objc objd . (Category objc c , Functor objc c objc c f, objc x)
           => c x x -> c (f (f x)) (f (f x))
doublefmap = (fmap @objc @c @objc @c @f . fmap @objc @c @objc @c @f)
```

I would be happy if someone can improve this.